# making a program that can play audio files in linux using oss by c language

Tags: c, linux, audio, open-source

I have a problem playing a audio file using OSS.
I want to play the file received from server by writing it on the soundcard in linux ubuntu.
the codes below are part of my socket programming.
I receive the file from the server then write the data in `recvBuf[]` to the soundcard using the `write()` part. The formats that I have tried to play on this program are pcm, wav, raw. I've heard that the OSS can play raw PCM files but I cannot exactly know what extension does the raw PCM file has.(or is just a modulation)

The two main things that I want to know are

1. Which type of audio file is playable with this program?

   - how do I have to set the variables(`RATE, CHANNELS, SIZE, BUFSIZE, ioctl(arguments)` etc.) to play this audio file?
2. if there are problems with this code, which part has what problems?

I referenced http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/research/epp/people/andrew_bennieston/projects/fragments/pcmplay.c

```
printf("opendev\n");
if ( (handle = open("/dev/dsp",O_RDWR)) == -1 )
{
    DWE("open");
}

if ( ioctl(handle,  SOUND_PCM_WRITE_BITS, &arg) == -1 )
{
    DWE("ioctl stereo");
}
if ( ioctl(handle, SOUND_PCM_WRITE_CHANNELS,&channels) == -1 )
{
    DWE("ioctl stereo");
}

if (ioctl(handle, SOUND_PCM_WRITE_RATE,&rate) == -1 )
{
    DWE("ioctl sample rate");
}

memset(recvBuf, 0,BUFSIZE);

printf("start\n");
while(!endOfList)
{

    if(recv(sock, &fileSize, 4, 0) < 0)
        DWE("fileSize recv fail");

    if(recv(sock, &msgSize, 4, 0) < 0)
        DWE("msgSize recv fail");

    if(recv(sock, musName, msgSize, 0) < 0)
        DWE("musName recv fail");

    printf("Playing %s...\n", musName);

    //if((fp = fopen(musName, "wb")) == NULL)
        //DWE("fopen musName fail");
    count = 1;

    while(out){         

        if(fileSize > BUFSIZE)
        {
            if((recvFileSize = recv(sock, recvBuf, BUFSIZE, 0)) < 0)
                DWE("file recv fail");
            fileSize -= recvFileSize;
            //fwrite(recvBuf, sizeof(unsigned char), BUFSIZE, fp);
            if(send(sock, &start, 4, 0) != 4)
                DWE("start send fail");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("recved file\n");                
            if(recv(sock, recvBuf, fileSize, 0) < 0)
                DWE("file recv fail");
            //fwrite(recvBuf, sizeof(unsigned char), fileSize, fp);
            out = 0;

        }

        if((status = write(handle, recvBuf, strlen(recvBuf))) == -1)
        {
            DWE("SOUND_write_ERROR");
        }
        count = 0;
        memset(recvBuf, 0, strlen(recvBuf));
    }
    printf("eol recv\n");
    if(recv(sock, &endOfList, 4, 0) < 0)
        DWE("eOL recv fail");

}
close(handle);
//fclose(fp);
```

}

Comment: BTW: OSS is in the current kernel marked as deprecated.

Comment: OSS has been superseded a long time ago by ALSA on Linux.  No guarantees that it's even present with many distros.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know OSS but this works with ALSA. But since you are using ubuntu, either ALSA is already there or you can install it easily.

First, you need to know the sampling rate, number of channels (mono or stereo) and bits per sample if you need to play back a RAW recording. If your incoming file is in .wav, then the file contains all the information regarding sampling rate and thus can be easily played by conventional media players or a custom program without you specifying them. RAW PCM recordings lack this information.

```
aplay -r 44100 -f S16_LE -c 1 <filename>
```

The above command (type it in ubuntu terminal) will play the RAW PCM recording . 44100 is the sampling rate, S16_LE denotes 16 bits per sample in little endian and the '1' denotes single channel (mono). If you set the sampling rate too much, then the playback will be squeaky. Set it too low and the recording will sound like angry dinosaurs. So in short, you need to know these parameters beforehand if you want to play the raw PCM as is.

But if you want to play back the file using a program, you will need the ALSA API. I'm a python fan and hence I used the pyalsaaudio API to play back the RAW PCM. The same task can be accomplished with the c API as well. The [pyalsaaudio](http://pyalsaaudio.sourceforge.net/) page has some relevant info. [These](http://pyalsaaudio.sourceforge.net/libalsaaudio.html#examples) examples demonstrate how to playback raw pcm and wav files.